# How do I get NLog to output to different targets depending on the solution configuration (release or debug)?

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, error-handling, nlog

I have a Win Forms, C#, .net app and am using NLog to log errors.  How can I get NLog to use different targets depending on whether I'm in debug or release mode?

For example, in debug mode I want all error messages to be sent only to me in an e-mail; in release mode I want all error messages to be sent to a group of people.  I'm trying to prevent errors done while testing from going to the whole group.

Answer (score 2):

Unload project in the solution explorer via context menu. Edit .csproj file. Add this strings into file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AppConfig>App.$(Configuration).config</AppConfig>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then you can have different settings for Debug and Release-build. When you run the Debug-build then it will use the `App.Debug.config`.

Then use `${appsetting}` layoutrenderer to lookup the email address to use. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AppSetting-Layout-Renderer (NLog 4.6.5 includes this out-of-the-box in NLog.dll)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply MSBuild config transformations to any config file, here is an article that explains it, I'm not going to post the details from the article due to the length of it.

https://johan.driessen.se/posts/Applying-MSBuild-Config-Transformations-to-any-config-file-without-using-any-Visual-Studio-extensions/